# How can Haskell manage / resample a series of irregular data?

Tags: haskell

**A DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM DOMAIN IS PROVIDED BELOW**

Given a `TimeStamp` defined as...

```
type TimeStamp = Int
```

a `DataPoint` defined as...

```
data DataPoint a = DataPoint {index :: TimeStamp, value :: a} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Foldable DataPoint where
  foldMap f (DataPoint _ y) = f y
```

a `Series` defined as...

```
data Series a = Series [DataPoint a]

instance Foldable Series where
  foldMap f (Series xs) = foldMap (foldMap f) xs
  length = size
```

and the following helpers:

```
emptySeries :: Series a
emptySeries = Series []

timeSeries :: [(TimeStamp, a)] -> Series a
timeSeries xs = Series $ map (uncurry DataPoint) xs

size :: Series a -> Int
size (Series xs) = length xs
```

How can I create a `timeSeries` of a specified resolution, given an irregular set of data. The resulting `timeSeries` should contain the most up-to-date value for every point in time, at the given resolution; to improve accessibility, the newest data is at the front of the `timeSeries`. For example...

if `irrData = [(98,5), (96,4), (93,9)]`, the resulting `timeSeries` would be `[(98,5), (97,4), (96,4), (95,9), (94,9), (93,9)]`

Bonus points if you can...

- use the same function to resample a `timeSeries` to a different resolution
- correctly parse data provided in any order (ex. [(98,5), (101,2), (93,4)]).

**MY CURRENT SOLUTION ATTEMPT IS PROVIDED BELOW, AND WILL CHANGE OVER TIME AS I WORK TOWARDS IT'S FINAL FORM**

The solution below functions as expected; I would still like to clean the code, as one line is very long. See the posted answer for details.

```
resample :: Int -> [(Int, v)] -> [(Int, v)]
resample _ [] = []
resample _ [x] = [x]
resample r xs = foldr (\i acc -> (i, snd $ head (filter (\x -> (fst x) <= i) s)):acc) [] [(fst $ head s), (fst $ head s) - r .. (fst $ last s)]
  where
    s = sortBy (flip $ on compare fst) xs
```

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a homework service. Make a fair attempt and come back
with *specific* questions about that attempt. See the
[*open letter to students with homework problems*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: I am not a student, and I am not looking for someone to do my work for me. As you can see, I have personally laid the foundations on which I am trying to build. This question is related to a personal project of mine, that I have have been working on for years. I originally started in Python, and only recently moved to Haskell as I believe it is more relevant. Even after reading "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good", I find myself needing help. I have invested a significant amount of my time in this project, and do not agree with your assessment about a "fair attempt".

Comment: @ReidJohnson The point is more fundamental than homework questions, it just often comes up in the context of students posting their homework assignments directly. If that's not your situation, that's fine, but the real issue is that the community generally expects questions like this to be in the form "I'm trying to implement X, here's the code I'm trying that doesn't work, can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?". You had instead just stated your requirements and asked how to implement them, which is pretty close to "looking for someone to do your work for you".

Comment: As I am not familiar with Haskell, there was a significant amount of work to get to this point. I felt that I was able to provide a good foundation, but I was struggling with the correct implementation. Being that you are likely much more experienced with Haskell, it may seem like this is an easy task; to me, this is a multi-layer problem in a space that I do not understand well. Regardless, I am making good progress and hope to have an answer to post soon.

Comment: I have uploaded a partial solution.

Comment: @ReidJohnson And nobody is saying that that kind of general "how should I approach this?" question isn't a legitimate kind of help to want; it's just that **this specific website** is set up for specific kinds of question, which doesn't include that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resample :: Int -> [(Int, v)] -> [(Int, v)]
resample _ [] = []
resample _ [x] = [x]
resample r xs = foldr (\i acc -> (i, snd $ head (filter (\x -> (fst x) <= i) s)):acc) [] [(fst $ head s), (fst $ head s) - r .. (fst $ last s)]
  where
    s = sortBy (flip $ on compare fst) xs
```

Given an `Int` resolution, and `[(Int, v)]` series, it will return a resampled series. The resulting series is bounded by the limits of the original series, with a point structure representing the new resolution; the value of each point represents the most up-to-date value from the original series.